# Styling bootstrap carousel navigation

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am trying to do something a little out of my league and im pretty close!

I want the prev/next buttons to be like this when you get to the page:

[image]

And like this when you hover (spread out and be ready to use)

[image]

I am at the first stage I am just having some issues with positioning if anyone can take a look.

[Here is the live site](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/) (just scroll to right below the portfolio)

Comment: I coudnt see scroller there

Comment: I check your live site , but i coudnt your issue there

Comment: If you scroll to where the carousel is (below portfolio) you can see the prev/next buttons are aligned to the right, I need them to be right below the name of the person who said the quote (warren buffet for example) and also I havent figured out the hover yet so the buttons stick together instead of spreading apart. Here is how I want it to look: http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/3.jpg

Comment: Just a heads up you large city scape picture loads pretty slowly for me. (I have a quick connection). Might want to optimise it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
.left.carousel-control:hover{
    margin-left:-50px;
}
.right.carousel-control:hover{
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Update :

```
.left.carousel-control, .right.carousel-control{
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok will have to play around with this a little, do you have any idea on the positioning?

Comment: Ok so this works pretty well, I just had to use padding instead of margin but I'm having an issue with it the `width: 100%;` causes the hover to be activated across the full width of the page, I am trying to fix it now if you can [take a look](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/)

Comment: Ok, you can change width to 40% and left to 30%     [30% empty, 40% controls, 30% empty]

Comment: Ok that is a lot better but it still activates 100 or so pixels outside the arrows, updated live site if you want to take a look!

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-control{top: 75%;}
.carousel-control.right{
right: 43%;
}
.carousel-control.left{
left: 42%;
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control.right{right: 0;}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control.left{left: 0;}
```

This might help.